# Access content page controls in pop up window(.aspx page) using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have a mater page. Within that I have a content page. I am opening a pop up window from this content page using using window.open method. I also tried opening a modal dialog box as an alternate option.

```
window.open("WebForm2.aspx?name1="+d+"&name2="e+,"MyWindow","height=375,width=350");
```

'd' & 'e'  are the control id,  that I have passed, and accessing in pop up window.

I want to access control values in the content page from the pop up(and vice-versa). All the controls that I am attemptimg. to access are in a gridview. However, I am unable to do so?

To acheive this,  I passed the specific values, that I intend to access, in the url, to the pop up window. This way the values are accessible but they seem very cumbersome.

```
alert(window.opener.document.getElementById(GetQueryStringParams('name1')).value);
```

```
function GetQueryStringParams(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find a way to access values of pop up page to content page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you definitely passing the full client ID (e.g. `ct100_master_ctrlId`) through the query string, and not JUST the ID (`ctrlId`)?

Comment: I am passing the entire Control ID, i.e. like ct100_master_ctrlId

Comment: It's possible that when you're pulling the querystring value that it's URL encoded.  There's a JavaScript function `decodeURIComponent()` that will decode the value for you.  i.e. amend the return statement in `GetQueryStringParams()` to `return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);`.  Maybe try that just in case?

Comment: I have used query string as I am not able to access the  pop-up controls directly from Content Page(and vice-versa). I am actually looking to avoid the query string approach as I am supposed to pass sensitive information